# PHP: executing a service start (with sudo)

Tags: php, system, centos, sudo

I am doing a system maintenance script that is checking the status of various services
(memcached, sphinx, etc)

I would like to start the service from php script if it is down...

I managed to do it for memcache like this:

```
$command = 'memcached -d -m 800 -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211 -u root start';
$dummy = system($command, $retval);
```

it is working GREAT...

now I'd like to do the same thing for SphinxSearch service

I tried

```
$command = 'service searchd start';
```

but got no result... and I read that I need sudo for this, so I did

```
$command = 'sudo service searchd start';
```

and even

```
$command = '/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/searchd';
```

but nothing worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
echo 'yourpassword' | sudo -S command
```

Comment: my root pass? I tried $command = 'echo ***** | sudo -u root -S /usr/bin/searchd';$dummy = system($command, $retval); ...no luck!

Comment: @DS_web_developer Verify whether you are providing proper password because it is working fine on my machine for `echo mypassword | sudo -u root mkdir /lib/test`

Comment: @DS_web_developer I guess if you are using a root user you need to provide a root password if you have changed it.

Comment: I am! I am providing the same pass I am using when logging in to my console (putty) ... tried the mkdir command too... and no dirs where created :(  ... echo mypass | sudo -u root mkdir /lib/test

Comment: I figured it out.... the poassword should be in single quotes like $command = "echo 'mypass' | sudo -u root .....";

Answer (score 1):

Users need permission to run `sudo`. Specifically, the user your PHP script is running as needs to be in the sudoers file. See `man sudoers` for information about the file. Use `visudo` to edit the sudoers file. Be very careful about giving your php/apache user permission to run sudo. It is a potential security issue that can allow your PHP scripts to do anything.

Comment: this is what I added to
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/myscript.php

but it is not working :(

Comment: I also tried:............... php ALL=(theuser) NOPASSWD: /path/to/myscript.php ...... and using it $command = 'sudo -u theuser service searchd start'; ...stil no success

Comment: You might need to add the path to each of the commands (sudo and service) because the PATH environment of your PHP script is different than your path. e.g. `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/service ...`

Comment: Maybe you should just give apache permissions to run the SphinxSearch service instead of trying to use sudo.